# The following assertion was thrown building _InkResponseStateWidget(gestures: [tap], mouseCursor: MaterialStateMouse

Tags: flutter

in my Flutter application, I am trying to put a dialog inside PopupMenuButton where in the dilaog, I am showing some application activity, but while I compile this code, get this error

I want the dialog open which has some activity to show

Comment: Talk is cheap, show us some code!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.